# Collections not getting created in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have created a new instance in mongodb and added authentication.

Post that while starting the springboot application the collections at the application which are annotated as @document are not getting created automatically.

But the dummy collection which I created while created  new db instance in mongo is getting  created.

Any help will.be appreciated

P.S there was an existing instance which was working fine.  Since to support multiple environments I was creating this separate instance

Answer (score 0):

You can find the collection created only when you do the a transaction of adding any document(i.e. record)in that collection. Which you can do by exposing a POST api /addResource that creates a document.

Comment: Thanks @jayshree sorry I missed that part.. on transaction it worked fine..